# Using os library on raspberry pi with serial read

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am new this Raspberry Pi and python. I am currently trying to take a picture when an IR beam is broken. I am using serial data from my Arduino which is where the IRLed and receiver is. I have tried this same code to light an LED and it seems to work fine. When I attempt to take the picture it just falls into a loop of taking picture after picture. I'm sure I'm missing something or doing something stupid.
-Note- Ideally I have an LED light up and a picture taken. I have removed the LED on code.

[screen snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYEhn.png)

Comment: 1) Please copy-paste your code into question instead of image. 2) Code looks ok to me. Probably arduino sends a lot of strings ( 0\r\n ) but you did not know about it - led would seem to light up once while you trying to set the same signal level at pin again and again.